# Implementing "Passive event listeners" in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I use a Chrome extension to modify the Zoom increments and it throw this error in the console:

```
Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
```

I tried to modify the extension to add the flag to make the event handler passive but it don't seem to work and I don't know why ?

Here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", function( event ) {
    if(enabled){
        //console.log("Scrolling Before: ",scrolling);
        if(!zooming){
            if(( event.wheelDeltaY > 0 || event.wheelDeltaY < 0 ) && !event.ctrlKey && !scrolling)
                scrolling = true;
        }
        //console.log("Scrolling: ",scrolling);
        if(!zooming && !scrolling){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                zooming = true;
                tempZoomLevel = zoomLevel;
                if( event.wheelDeltaY > 0  ) {
                    tempZoomLevel += zoomIncrement;
                }
                if( event.wheelDeltaY < 0 ) {
                    tempZoomLevel -= zoomIncrement;
                }
                if((Date.now() - lastZoomEvent) > zoomDelay){
                    lastZoomEvent = Date.now();
                    zooming = false;
                    zoomLevel = tempZoomLevel;
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({zoom: zoomLevel, lastZoom:lastZoomEvent, from:"content"}, function(response) {
                    });
                }
                else
                    zooming = false;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        /*else{

        }*/
        return false;
    }
}, {capture: true} );  /* Passive event listeners Mikhoul */
```

At the end you will see that I've added the "flag"  `{capture: true}` but I alway have this error in the console:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/SDmGdVo.png]

Also here's a link to the whole addon I have modified for my personal use if you need to look at the code in his entirety: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/olon2g04mifo7gh/ZommIncrementsFork.zip

**What I've missed to make the listener passive and stop to throw this error in the console ?**

Regards!

Comment: Uhm, see the documentation, it's: `passive: true`.

Comment: @wOxxOm  Thanks you are right, I was confused by this in the documentation: https://i.imgur.com/GLHLcGT.png  Source: https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

you need to set `passive: true` in your event handler, like this:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", function( event ) {
  // all of your function code
  // ...
}, { passive: true})
```

Comment: Thanks you are right, I was confused by this: https://i.imgur.com/GLHLcGT.png  Source: https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md